# How to refence current object (F object) within RawSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My `Order` model looks like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    billing_email = models.EmailField()
    ...
```

Desired output I am looking for is a `ValuesQuerySet` that would contain some fields values and a calculated value of the amount of orders with the same `billing_email`.

I was trying to reference `billing_email` with `F` object but doing the following results into error:

```
In [68]: orders = Order.objects.annotate(
    total_orders=RawSQL(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM appname_order WHERE billing_email = %s",
        (F('billing_email'),)  # current instance's billing_email
    ),
)

In [69]: orders
Out [70]: ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'F'
```

Pretty much the value I need to evaluate and output as an extra field for each instance is:

```
Order.objects.filter(billing_email__iexact=<current_billing_email>).count()
```

for each instance and I really wouldn't want to loop through actual instances and reconstruct. I must be missing some simple solution here.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I think usign F() allows you to get the value of a column or a field without pull it from DB. See the [class F docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F).

Comment: Thanks but doesn't really help with my problem. The issue is that I need to reference `this` (current) row's value (`billing_email`) on the go to construct extra output

Answer (score 5):

You can reference the "current" row using the table name of your Model:

```
RawSQL( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM appname_order order WHERE order.billing_email =appname_order.billing_email",[])
```